# How to insert newline in python logging?

Tags: python, logging, newline, python-logging

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
logging.info('hello')
logging.warning('\n new hello')
```

> 11:15:01 INFO hello
>   11:16:49 WARNING
>    new hello

Because the log is crowded, I want to explicitly insert a newline *before* `asctime` and `levelname`. Is this possible without modifying `format`?

I looked into `logging` module and googled a bit and could not find a viable way.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I have two solutions, the first is very easy, but the output is not very clean. The second method will produce the exact output you want, but it is a little more involved.

## Method 1

To produce a blank line, just log an empty string with a new line:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
logging.info('hello')
logging.info('\n')
logging.warning('new hello')
```

The output will have an empty info line, which is not very clean:

> 16:07:26 INFO hello
>   16:07:26 INFO
>
> 16:07:26 WARNING new hello

## Method 2

In this method, I created two different handlers. The `console_handler` which I use most of the time. When I need a new line, I switch to a second handler, `blank_handler`.

```
import logging
import types

def log_newline(self, how_many_lines=1):
    # Switch handler, output a blank line
    self.removeHandler(self.console_handler)
    self.addHandler(self.blank_handler)
    for i in range(how_many_lines):
        self.info('')

    # Switch back
    self.removeHandler(self.blank_handler)
    self.addHandler(self.console_handler)

def create_logger():
    # Create a handler
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    console_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt="%(name)s %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s"))

    # Create a "blank line" handler
    blank_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    blank_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    blank_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt=''))

    # Create a logger, with the previously-defined handler
    logger = logging.getLogger('logging_test')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    # Save some data and add a method to logger object
    logger.console_handler = console_handler
    logger.blank_handler = blank_handler
    logger.newline = types.MethodType(log_newline, logger)

    return logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = create_logger()
    logger.info('Start reading database')
    logger.info('Updating records ...')
    logger.newline()
    logger.info('Finish updating records')
```

The output is what you want to see:

```
logging_test INFO    : Start reading database
logging_test INFO    : Updating records ...

logging_test INFO    : Finish updating records
```

## Discussion

- If you can put up with the less-than-perfect output, method 1 is the way to go. It has the advantage of being simple, least amount of effort.
- The second method does the job correctly, but it is a little involved. It creates two different handlers and switch them in order to achieve your goal.
- Another disadvantage of using method 2 is you have to change your code by searching for `logging` and replacing them with `logger`. You must take care replacing only relevant parts and leave such text as `logging.DEBUG` in tact.

Comment: Another disadvantage of Method 1 is that if a different worker logs something in between, it's hard to follow the trace.

Answer (score 19):

Could you not add the newline after the first hello? i.e.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
logging.info('hello\n')
logging.info('new hello')
```

Which will output

```
2014-08-06 11:37:24,061 INFO    : hello

2014-08-06 11:37:24,061 INFO    : new hello
```

Comment: I thought this was the obvious solution at first too, but then the blank lines would depend on the logging level.

Comment: @delrocco, if you set `handler.setFormatter(None)` before logging the newline, I think you can use the same `logging.info('\n')` print, for instance, regardless of the logging level, since no format header for that given log level would be printed with the newline. Then, when done, restore the format with `handler.setFormatter(formatter)`. I haven't tested this, but it seems to me it should work. If it does, maybe I should make it a new answer.

Answer (score 13):

Easiest way to insert newlines that I figured out:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s\n\r%(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
logging.info('hello')
logging.info('new hello')
```

> 11:50:32 INFO
>   hello
>   11:50:32 INFO
>   new hello

Comment: this will display `\n\r` verbatim in python 3.6.1

Answer (score 10):

Use a custom `Formatter` which uses different format strings at different times. You can't do this using `basicConfig()` - you'll have to use other parts of the `logging` API.

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        # set self._fmt to value with or without newline,
        # as per your decision criteria
        # self._fmt = ...
        return super(MyFormatter, self).format(record)
```

Or, you can call the `super` method, then modify the string to insert a newline before returning it (in case it's dependent on line length, say).

Comment: you could follow this approach, but edit `record.msg` if you want to add new lines into the actual message itself.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Hai Vu's **Method 2** you could as well reset the handler's `Formatter` every time you want to log a new line:

```
import logging
import types

def log_newline(self, how_many_lines=1):
    # Switch formatter, output a blank line
    self.handler.setFormatter(self.blank_formatter)

    for i in range(how_many_lines):
        self.info('')

    # Switch back
    self.handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)


def create_logger():
    # Create a handler
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(name)s %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s")        
    blank_formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)


    # Create a logger, with the previously-defined handler
    logger = logging.getLogger('logging_test')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    # Save some data and add a method to logger object
    logger.handler = handler
    logger.formatter = formatter
    logger.blank_formatter = blank_formatter
    logger.newline = types.MethodType(log_newline, logger)

    return logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = create_logger()
    logger.info('Start reading database')
    logger.info('Updating records ...')
    logger.newline()
    logger.info('Finish updating records')
```

Output

```
logging_test INFO    : Start reading database  
logging_test INFO    : Updating records ...

logging_test INFO    : Finish updating records
```

The advantage of this is that you have a single handler. For example you can define a `FileHandler`'s `mode`-attribute to write, if you wanted to clean your log-file on every new run of your program.

Comment: I'm curious: Why is this solution not thread-safe while the original is not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll answer to myself. This is not thread-safe, because if one thread will write a new line and if now another thread will log information before the formatter has been reset by the former thread, the latter will log with an empty formatter, which we don't want.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking to output some debug code in development then you may not want to spend time on this. The 5 second fix is this;

```
str = "\n\n\n"
log.getLogger().debug(str)
```

where the logger is the standard python logger

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. Add `\n` into you [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) between `asctime` and `levelname`

```
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s\n %(levelname)s %(message)s',datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I need newline only for special occasions. Most of the time original  format is fine.

Comment: This is simple. I add <p> tags at beginning and end to inspect the file remotely in browser. not the best but neat

Answer (score 1):

What about writing to the log file, without the logging service?

```
fn_log = 'test.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=fn_log, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
logging.info('hello')
logging.warning('no empty line')

def empty_line(fn_log):
    new_empty_line = open(fn_log,'a+')
    new_empty_line.write('\n')
    new_empty_line.close()

empty_line(fn_log)
logging.warning('hello')
```

Output:

```
09:26:00 INFO hello
11:51:05 INFO hello
11:51:05 WARNING no empty line

11:51:05 WARNING hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Vinay Salip's helpful answer (below), I did it this way (I'm using the python3 superclass convention, but `super(MyFormatter, self)` works just as well) ...

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        return super().format(record).replace(r'\n', '\n')
```

Then, I can embed newlines as follows:

```
logging.info('Message\\n\\n\\n\\nOther stuff')
```

or

```
logging.info(r'Message\n\n\n\nOther stuff')
```

Answer (score 0):

Practically you can insert new line on log just by setting terminator property of StreamHandler.

```
def getLogger()
  lshell = logging.StreamHandler()
  lshell.setLevel(level=logging. DEBUG)
  dash = ' '.join( list(repeat('-',20)) )
  lshell.terminator = f'\n{dash}\n'

  lgr = logging.Logger(name='logname')
  lgr.addHandler(lshell)
  return lgr
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use FileHandler or descendants thereof, these two functions may help. An added benefit is that all FileHandler type handlers attached to the logger should get the newline.

```
def getAllLoggerFilenames(logger):
  """ Returns array of all log filenames attached to the logger. """
  logFiles = [];
  parent = logger.__dict__['parent'];
  if parent.__class__.__name__ == 'RootLogger':
    for h in logger.__dict__['handlers']:
      if h.baseFilename:
        logFiles.append(h.baseFilename);
  else:
    logFiles = getAllLoggerFilenames(parent);
  return logFiles;

def logBlankLine(logger):
  """ This utility method writes a blank line to the log. """
  logNames = getAllLoggerFilenames(logger)
  for fn in logNames:
    with open(fn, 'a') as fh:
      fh.write("\n")
```

Usage:

```
# We use YAML for logging config files, YMMV:
with open(logConfig, 'rt') as f:
  logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.safe_load(f.read()))

logger = logging.getLogger("test.test")

logger.info("line 1")
logBlankLine(logger)
logger.info("line 2")
```

Output:

```
2019/12/22 16:33:59.152: INFO    : test.test                 : line 1

2019/12/22 16:33:59.152: INFO    : test.test                 : line 2
```

Comment: Opening a second handle to the file to write the blank is not guaranteed to work as your example shows. Most OSs will not guarantee that the log writes from the two handles will be serialised.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest solution is to use f-strings if you are using Python 3:

```
logging.info( f'hello\n' )
```

Comment: Python 3.6+, specifically.

Comment: the use of f-strings in your code is meaningless...  there's no difference to using an ordinary string in here...

Answer (score -4):

You can try the following solution. It's simple and straightforward.

```
logging.debug("\b" * 20)  # output blank line using escape character
logging.debug("debug message")
```

Comment: lmao what hack is this