# How to add a new line or a separator between two logs

Tags: python-3.x, flask

The below code is for logging

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

if app.debug is not True:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('error.log', maxBytes=1024 * 1024 * 100, backupCount=20)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

How can I add a seperator (a new line or group of hyphens) after every new log created ?

After suggestion in the comments :

```
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s \n")
```

I got as:

```
2020-03-11 15:36:31,289 - testapp - ERROR - Exception on /test/3456789876543333334567-letter-words [GET]   
**newline added here**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-03-11 15:36:31,289 - testapp - ERROR - Exception on /test/3456789876543333334567-letter-words [GET]   
**newline added here**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
```

But I wanted something like:

```
2020-03-11 15:36:31,289 - testapp - ERROR - Exception on /test/3456789876543333334567-letter-words [GET]    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
**newline to be added here**
2020-03-11 15:36:31,289 - testapp - ERROR - Exception on /test/3456789876543333334567-letter-words [GET]   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
```

Comment: Did you try adding `\n` at the end of the `logging.Formatter()` string input?

Comment: I have got this to add a `\n` but didn't know where i could add that exactly

Comment: @Arnaud no effect after adding it mate ......

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert newline in python logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111758/how-to-insert-newline-in-python-logging)

Comment: No i have already seen and tried the same , ....

Comment: @Arnaud I have edited the Question with your suggested options and required output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line:

```py
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
```

with this:

```py
formatter = logging.Formatter("\n%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s\n")
```

Comment: Wow thanks mate .... couldn't think of this adding a '\n' at the start actually saves !!