# Is there a way to print a formatted dictionary to a Python log file?

Tags: python, python-logging

I've got a logging handler setup that prints to stream and file. I'm working with a few dictionaries and modifying dictionaries. Is there a way to format a dictionary for the log file so that it shows up as one block rather than a line?

I've gone through a bunch of simpler formatting attempts and read through [How to insert newline in python logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111758/how-to-insert-newline-in-python-logging). Before I try writing a custom formatter just for dictionaries, wanted to find out if there's a known way to do this. Thanks!

The desired output would be something like this:

```
2024-02-13 13:27:03,685 [DEBUG] root: shelf_name = 'some shelf',
                                      url = 'http://a_url',
                                      creation_date = '02/12/2024'
2024-02-13 13:34:55,889 [DEBUG] root:
```

So is there any way to do this for a dictionary block?

**UPDATED: Removed the old extraneous iterations. I'm posting the closest acceptable result, but still would like to make the dictionary print as a single block**

```py
class Downloader:
    def __init__(self, shelf_data) -> None:
        shelf = ShelfData(shelf_data)
        [logging.debug(f"shelf['{key}']: {val}") for key, val in shelf.__dict__.items()]
```

Log file:

```
2024-02-13 16:29:18,024 [DEBUG] root: shelf['shelf_name']: test_shelf
2024-02-13 16:29:18,024 [DEBUG] root: shelf['url']: https://site/group/show/1865-scifi-and-fantasy-book-club
2024-02-13 16:29:18,024 [DEBUG] root: shelf['base_path']: C:\MyProjects\downloads
2024-02-13 16:29:18,024 [DEBUG] root: shelf['creation_date']: 02/12/2024
2024-02-13 16:29:18,039 [DEBUG] root: shelf['sort_order']: descend
2024-02-13 16:29:18,039 [DEBUG] root: shelf['books_per_page']: 100
2024-02-13 16:29:18,039 [DEBUG] root: shelf['download_dir']: None
2024-02-13 16:29:18,039 [DEBUG] root: shelf['book_count']: 37095
2024-02-13 16:29:18,039 [DEBUG] root: shelf['page_count']: 371
```

Also, might as well add my logger:

```
    logging_config = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'standard': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'default_handler': {
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'formatter': 'standard',
                'filename': os.path.join('logs', f'{log_name}.log'),
                'encoding': 'utf-8'
            },
            'stream_handler': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'formatter': 'standard',}
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {
                'handlers': ['default_handler', 'stream_handler'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': False
            }
        }
    }
    logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)
```

Comment: Possible (partial) duplicate [How to insert newline in python logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111758/how-to-insert-newline-in-python-logging) At least the newline thing is explained there. You might be able to figure out the dictionary part yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I had read that question before posting. Solutions seem to focus on when data gets logged before or after separate targeted info. I'm interested in the the dictionary block which seems to be the tricky part. I only included the `\n` format in case someone else thought that a solution. I'll specify that above.

Comment: Can you show what your preferred output would look like? Ideal would be a [mre] including a sample input directory and how you intend for it to be logged.

Comment: Do you mean dictionary? Anyway, I added my desired output format above (sorry!).

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, and I think formatting the rest of the log line by computing the distance to the start of the line and adding both `\n` and an appropriate number of spaces between each field should do the trick - but I wanted to point out that you're creating a log file format that won't be useful to most software that can help analyse logs. You typically don't want lines in a log that don't start with the specific format - if you insist on having the dict in there, it would make more sense in a json encoding on a single line. Consider the value vs. the representation.

Comment: Don't do this. You'll just set yourself a trap for the future (self inflicted technical debt).

Comment: Hmm, so should I be researching how to anaylze JSON log files in order to deal with dictionaries? I'm looking at https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/json-logging/ as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but I leveraged the `pprint` module to pretty-print dictionaries storing configurations for various things in an app I'm working on.

The helper function and usage is below:

```py
import pprint
import logging

# set up pretty printer
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2, sort_dicts=False)

def log_pretty(obj):
    pretty_out = f"{pp.pformat(obj)}"

    return f'{pretty_out}\n'

# set up and log as usual
logger = logging.getLogger("myapp")

logger.info(f'You could print your logging_config dict like so:\n{log_pretty(logging_config)}')
```

You can also tweak the `pprint` options to your liking... see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html).

Comment: This answered my immediate question and short-term goal, but I guess leaves future conflicts possible per comments from Grismar and MatBailie.

Comment: I'm also a bit unsatisfied. There's obvious drawbacks as mentioned when logging for production systems, but I really just wanted something that my human eyes could parse easily to troubleshoot issues of complex configurations being passed around in development.  I'm actually not a fan of `pprint`s formatting, and might switch to using `json.dumps` in my stdout log.

I tried piping my console into `jq` as suggested in the link, but that wasn't working - or I've done something else wrong/incompatible. Perhaps I need to actually print out json and not Python dicts.